# How do I hold multiple functions in an array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I am new to MATLAB so I don't even know if this is possible, but here it is...
I am trying to print multiple lines in a single graph using the plot function. The problem is, I want to be able to specify how many lines the graph should display by simply changing a variable, for example: {This is the pseudo code to what I want to do}

```
 number_of_lines = 4;
 x = 0:0.5:5;

 function_output[number_of_lines];

 for n=0:number_of_lines
     function_output[n] = sin(n + x);
 end

 for n=0:number_of_lines
     plot(x,function_output[n]);
 end
```

I know the above pseudo code isn't exactly MATLAB, but all I want to know if such algorithm is possible to do in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to implement your example in MATLAB:

```
function_output = zeros(numel(x), number_of_lines);  % Initialize a 2-D array
for n = 1:number_of_lines                   % MATLAB uses 1-based indexing
    function_output(:, n) = sin(n + x).';  %' Compute a row vector, transpose
                                            %   it into a column vector, and
                                            %   place the data in a column of
                                            %   the 2-D array
end
plot(x, function_output);  % This will plot one line per column of the array
```

And here are some documentation links you should read through to learn and understand the above code:

- [Matrices and Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html)
- [Matrix Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)
- [Arithmetic Operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/arithmetic-operators.html)
- The [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through the MATLAB manual? -- it is quite well-written with many examples. Copy the example scripts and paste them onto the Command Window and see what happens...

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f9-53405.html

You can either write a script or use their plotting tool:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f9-47085.html

--- script example

> number_of_lines = 4;
>
> x = 0:0.5:5;
>
> function_output=ones(number_of_lines,1)*nan;
>
> figure;hold on;
>
> for n=1:number_of_lines
>
> function_output(n,1) = plot(x,sin(n+x),'color',[1-n/number_of_lines 0 n/number_of_lines]);
>
> end
>
> legend(function_output)

Have fun .

Comment: Question: What if I want to plot only when x is 3. Should by if statement be if( x == 3) ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly (I'm guessing here), you wish to plot only the n==3 ?  In other words, you wish to plot only the 3rd line?  If that is the case, yes - you can add: if (n==3); <plot the line>; end